# Get text location in chrome

Tags: javascript

I know we could get the location of an element on the page, but is it possible to retrieve the location of a text in Firefox or Chrome using javascript?

Comment: Do you want the location of a particular text node or of a selection (a range of characters within one text node or spanning multiple text nodes)?

Comment: Yes, text are nodes in the DOM tree, so all you have to do is recursively walk the thing and see if the textContent of a node matches your string.  *waves hands and waits for someone to answer ;)*

Comment: Yes location in coordinates for an entire text node. Like pageX & pageY.

Comment: This is a fairly tough question.  I am sure its possible with relatively low amounts of code w/ recursion/jQuery, but its not easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether you know this, but to establish the coordinates of a DOM element within its parent's box you need to access the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` of the element. To find the coordinates within the entire displayed page, you need to accumulate these values over the chain of `offsetParent` elements until you reach an element with no parent. The code looks like this

```
function coords(element) {
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  while (element.offsetParent) {
    x += element.offsetLeft;
    y += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return [x,y];
}
```

Now, to do this for an arbitrary piece of text within the page, if it has a parent element you simply find the position of that element. If not then write some JavaScript to enclose the text in `<span>` ... `</span>` tags - either by fiddling with `innerHTML` or preferably by working with the DOM tree, something like this

```
var span = createElement('span');
textNode.parentNode.insertBefore(span, textNode);
span.appendChild(textNode);
```

after which `coords(span)` will return the values you need.